# Pigeonholing mod 4 points on plane.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I have the following problem as homework. Suppose there are 13 points in the plane, all with integer coordinates. Prove at least one quadrilateral with vertices on those points has a barycentre with integer coordinates.

Comment: According to Mathworld, "The centroid of the vertices of a quadrilateral $ABCD$ occurs at the point of intersection of the bimedians (i.e., the lines $M_{AB}M_{CD}$ and  $M_{AD}M_{BC}$ joining pairs of opposite midpoints)." From this, and a parity argument, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem relies on this classical problem, given $5$ points on the plane there are $2$ of them which have a midpoint with integer coordinates. This problem is easy since there are $4$ possibilities for the parities of an ordered pair $(x,y)$. Thus there are two which have the same parity $(x,y)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$. Thus the $x_1+x_2$ and $y_1+y_2$ are even, which makes the midpoint have integer coefficients.

To solve the problem here we use this result to extract a pair of points with integer coordinates, we have $11$ remaining points, do it again, we now have $9$ points. Do this after you take out $5$ pairs of points and there are $3$ points remaining, forget about those $3$ extra points.

You know have $5$ line segments with midpoints with integer coordinates. So $5$ midpoints, so there are $2$ of these midpoints that have a midpoint with integer coordinates. Take these midpoints let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$ and $L$ the midpoint of $CD$. Then the midpoint of $ML$ is the barycentre of $ABCD$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Each point on the plane is of one of the following forms. $(o, o), (e, e), (o, e), (e, o)$ where $o$ and $e$ stands for odd and even integers. Since there are $13$ points on the plane - by the pigeonhole principle - at least $4$ of them are of the same form. That is  there are $4$ points on the plane $A, B, C, D$ such that each of their first coordinates are pairwise congruent modulo $2$ and each of their second coordinates are pairwise congruent modulo $2$.

Now think the vectors representing the points $A, B, C, D$ are $ \vec a, \vec b, \vec c, \vec d$. where the $\vec i, \vec j$ components of the vectors are pairwise congruent to each other modulo 2.

According to @John above, the medians of the bisecting points of the lines joining the vectors will be $\frac {\vec a + \vec b}{2}, \frac{  \vec b + \vec c} {2}, \frac {  \vec c  + \vec d }{2}, \frac {  \vec d + \vec a}{2}$. The intersection of the lines $M_{AB}M_{CD}$ and $M_{AD}M_{BC}$ is the solution to the following two equations.

$$\vec r = t \left[{ \frac {  \vec c  + \vec d }{2} - \frac {\vec a + \vec b}{2}   }\right] + \frac {\vec a + \vec b}{2} -------(1)$$

$$ r = s \left[{  \frac{  \vec b + \vec c} {2} -  \frac {  \vec d + \vec a}{2}  }\right] +  \frac {  \vec d + \vec a}{2}-------(2) $$

The above two vectors will be equal  when the parameters $t = s= \frac 1 2$ and hence I believe this is the point of intersection of $M_{AB}M_{CD}$ and $M_{AD}M_{BC}$ - (*correct me if I'm wrong*).

Now the vector representing the barycentre is $$\vec r = \frac { \vec a + \vec b + \vec c + \vec d}{4}$$

Now, like I said since the components of each each of the vectors $ \vec a, \vec b, \vec c, \vec d$ is congruent modulo 2 to each other's components, it can be seen that the components of $\vec r$ are integers.

I'm not a 100% sure about this solution. But this problem enthuses me and hope this would help you to come up with an answer.

Comment: Footnote: Sorry about the lousy terms here and there I learnt Geometry in Sinhalese (not in English) in school so my nomenclature is not so great..

Comment: You may or may not be right about the $s = t = 1/2$ claim (I *think* that you are), but an alternative formulation is this: "In addition, it is the midpoint of the line $M_{AC}M_{BD}$ connecting the midpoints of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. " Your analysis, applied to that statement (the midpoint of the diagonal $AC$ is $(a+c)/2$; that of $BD$ is $(b+d)/2$, and the midpoint of those two is $(a+b+c+d)/2$), gives the result. Nicely done!

Comment: @John: You're right! That is much easier and clearer. Guess I wasn't too familiar with the definition of a centroid. And I believe you meant $ (a + b + c + d) / 4 $ above.. And Thanks!

Comment: Right you are...but I can no longer edit it. Sigh.

Comment: 1+3+3+3=10 is not divisible by 4. Yes, you got all the goemetry part right. Only the combinatorics part is what I'm struggling with.I still appreciate what you did.

Comment: @user4140: You're dead right. I apologise profusely. And that's the second false answer I've posted today. I'm still pretty sure about the application of the pigeonhole principle. Am I interpreting the barycentre correctly??

Comment: Yes, you can take it as the sum of the 4 coordinates divided by 4. However you don't need all 4 of the points to be congruent mod 4. That's why I'm not so sure where to pigeonhole.